# Is there a way to extract comments from code files with DTE (Visual Studio Automation)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I want to extract comments from code files in a Visual Studio extension. Is there a way to do it using Visual Studio Automation without having to parse code text myself?

PS: Roslyn is not a choice, because I'm not restricted to C# and VB.NET only.

Comment: Difference languages have different parsers, so I don't think VS has a unified interface to expose the AST from parsers to extensions. It is likely that parsing the code on your own is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Various code elements like [CodeClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.codeclass?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and [CodeFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.codefunction?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) have the Comment property that return the header comment, accessible using Visual Studio code model.

And if a document is opened in VS editor, you can check SnapshotSpan classifications for PredefinedClassificationTypeNames.Comment.